# How do I impute NaNs as means() but by a multi-index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a datastructure that looks like this:

```
S1  D1  1   2   3   4   5
    D2  2   Nan 3   4   5
    D3  3   4   5   Nan 6
S2  D4  Nan 3   4   5   6
    D5  6   7   8   9   0
S3  D6  3   4   5   6   7
    D7  4   5   6   7   Nan
    D8  5   6   7   7   8
    D9  2   3   4   5   6
```

The S's are different States, and the D's different Districts. How do I impute the NANs as means the columns but just for the corresponding States, not means of the over all columns?

Totally stymid on this one, any help appreciated.

the output should look something like this:

```
S1  D1  1   2   3   4   5
    D2  2   3   3   4   5
    D3  3   4   5   4   6
S2  D4  6   3   4   5   6
    D5  6   7   8   9   0
S3  D6  3   4   5   6   7
    D7  4   5   6   7   7
    D8  5   6   7   7   8
    D9  2   3   4   5   6
```

Not this which averages the whole columns:

```
S1  D1  1   2   3   4   5
    D2  2   4.25    3   4   5
    D3  3   4   5   5.87    6
S2  D4  3.25    3   4   5   6
    D5  6   7   8   9   0
S3  D6  3   4   5   6   7
    D7  4   5   6   7   4.25
    D8  5   6   7   7   8
    D9  2   3   4   5   6
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `transform`

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(level=0).transform('mean'))

         2    3  4    5    6
0  1                        
S1 D1  1.0  2.0  3  4.0  5.0
   D2  2.0  3.0  3  4.0  5.0
   D3  3.0  4.0  5  4.0  6.0
S2 D4  6.0  3.0  4  5.0  6.0
   D5  6.0  7.0  8  9.0  0.0
S3 D6  3.0  4.0  5  6.0  7.0
   D7  4.0  5.0  6  7.0  7.0
   D8  5.0  6.0  7  7.0  8.0
   D9  2.0  3.0  4  5.0  6.0
```

Comment: Quite simply, you rock. Thank you, worked perfectly first time.

Comment: This worked for me to implement a simple interpolate/extrapolate: df.fillna(df.groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='linear').bfill().ffill() )

Answer (score 4):

```
In [354]: df.fillna(df.mean(level=0))
Out[354]:
         2    3  4    5    6
0  1
S1 D1  1.0  2.0  3  4.0  5.0
   D2  2.0  3.0  3  4.0  5.0
   D3  3.0  4.0  5  4.0  6.0
S2 D4  6.0  3.0  4  5.0  6.0
   D5  6.0  7.0  8  9.0  0.0
S3 D6  3.0  4.0  5  6.0  7.0
   D7  4.0  5.0  6  7.0  7.0
   D8  5.0  6.0  7  7.0  8.0
   D9  2.0  3.0  4  5.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thank you Max, work like a dream, just like the one below.